# Unrecognized option: --illegal-access=permit when running cordova build android

Tags: android, android-studio, cordova, ionic-framework

I'm running an ionic project and I'm getting the following errors when I run `ionic cordova build android`:

```
Unrecognized option: --illegal-access=permit
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```

This happened immediately I updated my ionic version and reinstalled JDK 8.My search online makes me understand it seems to be a very recent issue with recent versions of `cordova-android` and no resource I found helped solve the problem.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Go to the path your project /platforms/android/

Edit the gradlew file

Look at the end of the file in the line eval set - $ DEFAULT_JVM_OPTS and remove **--illegal-access = permit**

Recompile and issue resolved

Comment: Manually editing `gradlew` can't be the real solution. What's causing this and how to fix it for real?

Comment: seems strange solution to change generated files... but it works.
probably there is an option to add/remove some property on generation ?

Answer (score 9):

I ran into this problem on a machine that turned out to have an old version of Gradle installed (4.x). After installing [current Gradle](https://gradle.org/install/) (7.2 as of this writing), and removing and re-adding Android to the Cordova project, I was able to build successfully.

Comment: I had installed gradle using apt, which installed gradle 4.1.1 (which is outdated). This was the solution (updated my version by using sdkman).

Answer (score 1):

This has to do with the Java Virtual Machine (JVM) version. The `--illegal-access=permit` option is not present int the Java 8 JVM. The Java 11 JVM, for example, does support it.

I ran into this today when running `gradle init` to create a gradle wrapper in my repository. `gradle init` itself was successful, but the resulting gradle wrapper sets that `--illegal-access=permit`, which caused any `./gradlew` commands I ran to fail.

So it seems that the default `gradle init` task assumes that you'll be using a newer JDK version.